# autowire beans.groovy in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, grails, groovy

Don't understand how properly use beans.groovy in java spring boot app.
I want change some values in my java beans like in xml, throught .groovy. How I can do it? I try that:
I have main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "proj")
public class Application   {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Object[] sources = {Application.class, new ClassPathResource("beans.groovy")};
    SpringApplication.run( sources , args);
    }
}
```

and some TestBean. There are 2 fields name and surname, that I want init trhought groovy:

```
@Component
public class TestBean {
    public String name;
    public String surname;

    TestBean(){
        System.out.println("INIT!!!!!");
    }
}
```

and I want init TesbBean through Groovy beans. I add somebeans.groovy file in resources and add that in it:
I want autowire it in my @Controller like it:@RestController

```
public class StaticContect {
@Autowired
TestBean testBean;
@RequestMapping(value = "test" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(testBean.name);
        System.out.println(testBean.surname);
    }
}
```

and I add somefile.groovy to resources with this content:

```
beans  {
      TestBean(){
        name = "nametest"
        surname = "surname"
    }
}
```

but I have null int name and surname.

Comment: Remove @Component annotation from TestBean definition

Comment: but than I have exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'staticContect': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: proj.config.TestBean

Comment: add somefile.groovy in ClassPathResource in main method

Comment: But I added it throughthelp "new ClassPathResource("beans.groovy")" , file beans.groovy exist in /main/resources/

Comment: mb I must add somethingelse in gradle?

Comment: Show us your beans.groovy file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113508/discussion-between-sangram-jadhav-and-dzrkot).

Comment: You can see it above , in my main post , last code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beans.groovy should be

```
import proj.config.TestBean

beans  {
      testBean(TestBean, name = "nametest", surname = "surname")
}
```